# trying to keep a game object within the screen left and right bounds in unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have this code bellow for my gameobject :

```
private float screenx;
Vector3 playerPosScreen;
 void Start () {
 screenx=Camera.main.pixelWidth-renderer.bounds.size.x ;
 }

 void update(){
  playerPosScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
  if (playerPosScreen.x >= screenx) {
        //playerPosScreen.x=screenx;
        transform.position=new Vector3 (screenx, transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
    }
    //txt.text = playerPosScreen.x.ToString();
    else if(playerPosScreen.x<=renderer.bounds.size.x){
        transform.position=new Vector3 (renderer.bounds.size.x, transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
    }
 }
```

I'm developing a `2D` game with an `orthographic` camera,my problem is the gameobject is keep on going out of screen , am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research i found a solution wish worked excellent with me :

```
Vector3 playerPosScreen;
Vector3 wrld;
float half_szX;
float half_szY;
void Start () {
    wrld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    half_szX = renderer.bounds.size.x / 2;
    half_szY = renderer.bounds.size.y /2 ;
}
void Update () {
    playerPosScreen = transform.position;
 if (playerPosScreen.x >=(wrld.x-half_szX) ) {
        playerPosScreen.x=wrld.x-half_szX;
        transform.position=playerPosScreen;
    }
    if(playerPosScreen.x<=-(wrld.x-half_szX)){
        playerPosScreen.x=-(wrld.x-half_szX);
        transform.position=playerPosScreen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your function is never called because there is typo in its name. It should be `Update` not `update`.

Secondly the problem with coordinates is that the code is mixing screen coordinates and world coordinates. Screen coordinates go from `(0, 0)` to `(Screen.width, Screen.height)`. Coordinates can be changed from world coordinates to screen coordinates with `WorldToScreenPoint` and back with `ScreenToWorldPoint`, in which the Z value is the distance of the converted point from camera.

Here is a complete code example, which can be used after changing the player's position to make sure that it is inside the screen area:

```
    Vector2 playerPosScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    if (playerPosScreen.x > Screen.width)
    {
        transform.position = 
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
                new Vector3(Screen.width, 
                            playerPosScreen.y, 
                            transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    }
    else if (playerPosScreen.x < 0.0f)
    {
        transform.position = 
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
                new Vector3(0.0f, 
                            playerPosScreen.y, 
                            transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    }
```

Comment: i am sorry for the typing error `update` it was just a typing mistake , and thank you for the tip about the clarification and the code . i shall test it :)

Comment: No problem. At least for me the code works on both Orthographic and Perspective camera.